# How to Restrict canvas size in wpf when Zoomed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am designing a Wpf in visual studio 2010 Application which is implementing zoom feature in Canvas.
The Event is:

```
  < canvas MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" />
```

and the backend in xaml.cs is:

```
  const double ScaleRate = 1.1;

  private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                st.ScaleX *= ScaleRate;
                st.ScaleY *= ScaleRate;
            }
            else
            {
                st.ScaleX /= ScaleRate;
                st.ScaleY /= ScaleRate;
            }
        }
```

The problem is when i am zooming the figure in canvas ,the whole canvas is expanding and taking the whole space which is undesired.Because i only want zoom in canvas not to expand it and also i have defined max height and max width as well.

Kindly Help me with This.

Comment: Can you provide us with the relevant xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        double maxScale = 2.0;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            st.ScaleX *= ScaleRate;
            st.ScaleY *= ScaleRate;
        }
        else
        {
            st.ScaleX /= ScaleRate;
            st.ScaleY /= ScaleRate;
        }

        if(st.ScaleX > maxScale)
        {
            st.ScaleX = maxScale;
        }

        if(st.ScaleY > maxScale)
        {
            st.ScaleY = maxScale;
        }

    }
```